# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck in boot /dev/sda5: recovering journal

Tags: boot

Like the title says ubuntu gets stuck on boot with the following text displayed on a black screen

```
/dev/sda5: recovering journal
/dev/sda5: clean, 585219/3137536 files, 11933163/12550144 blocks
```

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu so how do I fix it?
Laptop is an HP Probook 6470b
Dual boot with windows 7. Windows still works

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Returned to Windows :(

Answer (score 2):

Let's check/repair your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`