# Ubuntu 22.04 stuck in boot

Tags: boot, partitioning

I'm new to Ubuntu. Recently i was trying to extend the partition where my Ubuntu installation is. I made some changes following some tutorials and now I have issues booting to Ubuntu. When I start the pc, it goes to a black box that says

/dev/sda5: recovering journal
...
Failed : system logging services

My SSD has a partition called dev/sda5 where the installation is. I tried with an usb Live USB follow this issue: [Ubuntu 20.04 stuck in boot /dev/sda5: recovering journal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292089/ubuntu-20-04-stuck-in-boot-dev-sda5-recovering-journal)

And now when I boot, it appears a prompt login form. When I put my info correctly goes back to that form

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Generally, the best information that is helpful in solving a problem is to know what caused the problem. You've seemingly identified the problem: *"i was trying to extend the partition where my Ubuntu installation is. I made some changes following some tutorials and now I have issues booting to Ubuntu"* But you didn't actually tell us what you did... Please be more specific and detailed. Tell us your exact actions and link to the resources you are referencing. Please edit your question. With more specific details, we are better equipped to assist.